# Having Trouble filtering mails in Outlook with certain Categories with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, categories

I have hundreds of mails in inbox and they can have any combination of mutiple categories ("AA","BB","CC","DD", etc.) which can be assigned in any order.
I want to select mails using only `.Items.Restrict` to filter mails that have "AA" and NOT have "BB", no matter if other categories are set or not. I'm trying to avoid looping all mails to check the `.categories` text string, which is a way to go but very slow.
I tried someting like this with no luck:

```
    sFilter = "[Categories] = 'AA' And Not([Categories] = 'BB')"
    Set oOlResults = oOlInb.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
```

Is that possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All possible combinations that do not include category BB.

```
sfilter = "[Categories] = 'AA' OR [Categories] = 'AA, CC' OR [Categories] = 'CC, AA'"
```

Comment: Thanks niton. I get your idea! But I had to edit my original post because I realized I simplified it too much using an example with only 3 categories that you solve smartly. In fact, there are dozens of categories in use. Sorry for not be clear enough. My fault!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to help someone with this same problem I will post what I've just found: this can be solved using DASL filter string. For this example:

```
sFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords"" like 'AA' AND NOT (""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords"" like 'BB')"
```